# How to hide the Text Color icon from Visual Editor of WordPress Post Editor from Users other than Admins?

Tags: visual-editor, post-editor

Want to hide the Text Color icon from Visual Editor of WordPress Post Editor from Users other than Admins.  How to do it?

Comment: Hi @Riya - Is this for Classic Editor or Gutenberg?

Comment: @LouisS Classic Editor

Comment: Ok, let me know if my answer below works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you add it to your functions.php file. It targets the buttons on the second row in your text editor. To target the first row, use the **mce_buttons** hook instead of **mce_buttons_2**.

```
/**
 * Removes text color button from tiny mce editor
 */
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'remove_tiny_mce_buttons');
function remove_tiny_mce_buttons( $buttons ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator')){
    $remove_buttons = array(
        'forecolor', // text color
    );
    foreach ( $buttons as $button_key => $button_value ) {
        if ( in_array( $button_value, $remove_buttons ) ) {
            unset( $buttons[ $button_key ] );
        }
    }

    }
    return $buttons;
}
```

If you would like to remove more buttons on the second row (mce_buttons_2), add their IDs to the **$remove_buttons** array. Below are a few second row IDs:

- formatselect
- underline
- alignjustify
- forecolor
- pastetext
- removeformat
- charmap
- outdent
- indent
- undo
- redo
- wp_help

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: Can this code be added to remove other buttons, for e.g: buttons with i class "mce-ico mce-i-et_bloom_shortcode_icon" ?

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I've edited my answer to explain how to remove more than one button, but I'm not sure if that 'bloom' button is affected by the mce_buttons_2 hook.

Comment: So kind of you. Here's the screenshot of the button marked with red arrow https://ibb.co/fGNq20z and this is the code:

<div id="mceu_13" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_13" role="button" aria-label="insert bloom Opt-In" aria-haspopup="true"><button id="mceu_13-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-et_bloom_shortcode_icon"></i> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div>